# Prove that the following three metric space/subsequence boundedness conditions are equivalent.

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Say I have a metric space $(M,d)$, and $A$ is a subset of $M$. I'm trying to prove that the following three conditions are equivalent.

$(\exists x \in M)$ $(\{d(x,y): y \in A\}$ is bounded)

$(\forall x \in M)$ $(\{d(x,y): y \in A\}$ is bounded)

$(\{d(x,y): x$ and $y \in A\}$ is bounded)

For the second condition leading to the first, if for all $x \in M$, $\{d(x,y): y \in A\}$ is bounded, then there certainly exists **at least** one $x \in M$ such that $(\{d(x,y): y \in A\}$ is bounded.

For the last condition leading to the first condition, I think if a distance function exists such that points in A are bounded, then there exists a point $x$ in M (that is also in A, presumably) such that distance function $d(x,y)$ is bounded for $y \in A$

Thoughts on how to prove equivalence formally?

Edit: The second condition being equivalent to the third is apparently more complicated than what I suggested in the comment below. (I had the third condition described to me as: For any arbitrary point (x,y) in A, the set of distances from (x,y) to other points in A is bounded.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you know how to prove $(iii)\implies (i)$. For $(i)\implies (ii)$, let $x_0$ be the point under $(i)$. Then for all $x\in M$ and $y\in A$, we have
$$
d(x,y)\leq d(x,x_0)+d(x_0,y)\leq d(x,x_0)+C,
$$
where $C$ is some constant, independent of $y$, by hypothesis.

See if you can handle $(ii)\implies (iii)$.

Comment: It seems like we can say: If $\forall x \in M$ mean $\{d(x,y):y\in A\}$ is bounded, then the same condition is true for points $x$ in $A$, as they are also contained in $M$. Hence the function $d(x,y)$ is bounded for both $x$ and $y$ in $A$. Hence (iii) is true. I don't think that's written formally enough, but is the thought correct?

Comment: @zuguzug My approach for (ii) -> (iii) would also be the triangle inequality, but I'm not seeing how to formally express it. I tried to reexpress condition three in the statement of the problem to explain where I'm getting foiled.

Comment: @BobMcdonald: For $(ii)\implies (iii):$ Take $z\in M$. Then for all $x,y\in A$, we have $d(x,y)\leq d(x,z)+d(z,y)$. By $(ii)$, There exists a bound that depends on $z$ (but not $x$ and $y$) such that $d(x,z)\leq C(z)$ and $d(z,y)=d(y,z)\leq C(z)$. Hence, $d(x,y)\leq 2 C(z)$, which is clearly an upper bound that does not depend on $x,y$.